# Python user-input

Tags: python, user-input

I'm trying to come up with a simple calculator that takes a user's input and does a calculation but it keeps throwing out errors.

```
raw = input("Raw Formatting:")
disk = input("On-disk formatting:")
slack = input("Slack space:")
quest = input("Select protection; 1=FTT, 2=EC-1, 3=EC-2:")

if quest == 1:
    answer = raw * (1-disk) * (1-slack) * 0.5
    print (answer)
elif quest == 2:
    answer = raw * (1-disk) * (1-slack) * 0.75
    print (answer)
elif quest == 3:
    answer = raw * (1-disk) * (1-slack) * 0.67
    print (answer)
else:
    print ("You didn't provide a valid protection level")
```

Output:

```
Raw Formatting:24
On-disk formatting:0.1
Slack space:0.3
Select protection; 1=FTT, 2=EC-1, 3=EC-2:1
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\hello.py", line 7, in <module>
  answer = raw * (1-disk) * (1-slack) * 0.5
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "but it keeps throwing out errors. " - Please include the error message in your question.

Comment: provide the traceback please

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, how do I do that?

Comment: BTW, you could put those protection level multipliers in a list. That way, you wouldn't need that big if-elif block with the almost-identical calculations.

Comment: `Raw Formatting:24
On-disk formatting:0.1
Slack space:0.3
Select protection; 1=FTT, 2=EC-1, 3=EC-2:1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\hello.py", line 7, in <module>
    answer = raw * (1-disk) * (1-slack) * 0.5
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: You should [edit] that info into your question. Put it in a code block to preserve formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thrustmaster's answer is correct:

You are taking an input, which is a string, no matter what is entered as input, then you are trying to perform a math operation with a string and an integer.

you need to convert your strings to ints or call them as ints when you are performing your math functions.

example one:

```
raw = input("Raw Formatting:")
disk = input("On-disk formatting:")
slack = input("Slack space:")
quest = input("Select protection; 1=FTT, 2=EC-1, 3=EC-2:")
raw = float(raw)
disk = float(disk)
slack = float(slack)
quest= float(quest)
if quest == 1:
    answer = raw * (1-disk) * (1-slack) * 0.5
    print (answer)
elif quest == 2:
    answer = raw * (1-disk) * (1-slack) * 0.75
    print (answer)
elif quest == 3:
    answer = raw * (1-disk) * (1-slack) * 0.67
    print (answer)
else:
    print ("You didn't provide a valid protection level")
```

Example 2

```
raw = input("Raw Formatting:")
disk = input("On-disk formatting:")
slack = input("Slack space:")
quest = input("Select protection; 1=FTT, 2=EC-1, 3=EC-2:")

if quest == '1':
    answer = float(raw) * (1-float(disk)) * (1-float(slack)) * 0.5
    print (answer)
elif quest == '2':
    answer = float(raw) * (1-float(disk)) * (1-float(slack)) * 0.75
    print (answer)
elif quest == '3':
    answer = float(raw) * (1-float(disk)) * (1-float(slack)) * 0.67
    print (answer)
else:
    print ("You didn't provide a valid protection level")
```

You will also need to check to make sure that what you are getting back will evaluate to integer, less you want more errors.. first thing you should do is strip spaces from you input

```
x = input('type a number: ').strip(' ')
```

then you should ensure that your input(string values) are numbers.

```
if not x.isdigit():
    print("you didn't enter a number")
```

Alternatively, there are more pythonic ways to perform the answer I have given, but I think the answer is appropriate for you currently
you should be able to work with that..
read the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/

Comment: I forgot to mention that the inputs for disk and slack are actually floats. Just changed them and it works now!

Comment: good to know, I edited my answer to floats instead of ints for you

Comment: But now the `.isdigit` stuff is irrelevant... I guess you could show how to do it using `try..except`. BTW, `int` and `float` cope with trailing space. Of course, you do need to get rid of trailing space if you want to use `.isdigit` to validate non-negative integers.

Comment: .isdigit() is relevant to checking if the string entered was a number prior to converting to an int or float. Like I said at the end of my answer, there are definitely more pythonic ways to accomplish this task.

Comment: OP, you should mark my answer as correct if it worked for you.

Comment: `.isdigit()` is not much use for testing if a string represents a valid float. What if the input is something like `1.2E-3` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a string against an integer.

You should do (with all the variables):

```
quest = int(input(" .... "))
```

and then compare the way you are doing currently.

Comment: or do `quest == '1' , quest == '2', quest == '3'`